# How do I merge a CSV in a one-to-many format with a split column and count?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, merge

I have two CSV files. File-X has 182,000 rows and File-Y has 1.5-million. They both have a field in common -- link_ID and location, respectively. I want to merge the two tables based on this common field, however, I want to also split one column into several columns to contain the respective totals.

**File-X format:**

linkid, linkx, linky

001, 55699, 4160239

002, 55698, 4130325

003, ..., ...

**File-Y format:**

person, mode, location

23, car, 001

40, car, 001

67, walk, 001

**What I would like to do:**

linkid, car, bike, walk

001, 2, 0, 1

002, 4, 2, 1

The link below is a screenshot with what I have so far but I am having difficulty splitting the mode column. From here, I think all I would need to do is the following code

DF1 join DF2 on

DF1.location = DF2.linkid

but I haven't quite got this far yet. The split has been throwing me in a loop.

[Data Frame 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTCtv.png)

This is the error message I get when trying to use the string split method for pandas.

[Data Frame Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDqZw.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it by grouping your File-Y by the location ID and counting the occurrences of each mode of transport for that `linkid`. We drop one level to ignore the counts of each person id in File-Y. Then you can join that back with File-X to get the `linkx` and `linky` columns if you need them.

```
import pandas as pd
file_x = pd.DataFrame(["001, 55699, 4160239".split(', '), "002, 55698, 4130325".split(', '), "003, 55699, 4130326".split(', ')], columns=['linkid', 'linkx', 'linky'])
file_y = pd.DataFrame(["23, car, 001".split(', '), "40, car, 001".split(', '), "67, walk, 001".split(', '), "68, bike, 002".split(', '), "69, car, 002".split(', '), "70, car, 002".split(', '), "71, car, 002".split(', ')], columns=['person', 'mode', 'location'])
merge_df = file_y.groupby(['location', 'mode']).count().unstack(level=1)
merge_df.columns = merge_df.columns.droplevel()
merge_df = pd.merge(merge_df, file_x, how='left', left_on='location', right_on='linkid')
```

`merge_df` will look like -

```
   bike  car  walk linkid  linkx    linky
0   NaN  2.0   1.0    001  55699  4160239
1   1.0  3.0   NaN    002  55698  4130325
```

Comment: Thank you so much Aryan Jain! I can't say with certainty that I fully understand everything but I got the output I was looking for. Here are two screenshots of my used code and the output.

[link](https://i.gyazo.com/e2219e100ce6d7ae579026dff78ae7bd.png) -- The Code
[link](https://i.gyazo.com/b4d609f78c4954590c3cb18b4662e7f1.png) -- The CSV

I cleaned up the data quickly in Excel and decided not to keep the XY locations and instead chose to just table-join this data into my ArcMap project.

I think, once i learn a little more about coding, I can do most of this in pandas. Thanks so much